# Google App Engine Missing subfolders in downloaded Source code

Tags: google-app-engine

I downloaded the source code from Container Registery>Build History.I can only see files in the root folder but cant find any sub folders
Where can I go to get subfolders too. I want to download complete code

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use Container Registry > Build History to generate the source code of an application (including folders). I tried to reproduce your issue, but got different results. Here are my reproduction steps:

1- Grab random Google Cloud Platform application on GitHub

```
git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples.git
```

2- Navigate to any sample application with folders (I used the static_files app)

```
cd [somepath]\python-docs-samples\appengine\flexible\static_files
```

3- Deploy application

```
gcloud app deploy --version some_version_name --promote
```

4- Downloaded source code on Container Registry > Build History > Select Build > Source (attached)

[image]

As you can see above, the folders 'templates' and 'static' are available. I also verified that file exists on those folders.

Let us know if you are able to achieve same results. Please provide error logs, if any.